# listBox And Jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

could any body explain me how can i save state of two list boxes on post back i am using jQuery of this kind i dont know on what event what should i do or where can i save view state or how can i use hiddenField to persist the state of both list box

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            //If you want to move selected item from fromListBox to toListBox
                $("#add").click(function() {
                    $("#"+'<%= fromListBox.ClientID %>'+" option:selected").appendTo("#"+'<%=toListBox.ClientID %>');
                });
                //If you want to move all item from fromListBox to toListBox
                $("#addAll").click(function() {
                    $("#"+'<%= fromListBox.ClientID %>'+" option").appendTo("#"+'<%=toListBox.ClientID %>');
            });
                //If you want to remove selected item from toListBox to fromListBox
                $("#remove").click(function() {
                    $("#"+'<%=toListBox.ClientID %>'+" option:selected").appendTo("#"+'<%= fromListBox.ClientID %>');
                });
                //If you want to remove all items from toListBox to fromListBox
                $("#removeAll").click(function() {
                    $("#"+'<%=toListBox.ClientID %>'+" option").appendTo("#"+'<%= fromListBox.ClientID %>');
                });

            });
                  </script>

<asp:ListBox ID="fromListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="150px" Width="150px"  >

<asp:ListItem Text="Student Enrollment ID" Value="enrollment_no"></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Text="Student Name" Value="first_name"></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Text="Last Name" Value="last_name"></asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Text="Father Name" Value="father_name"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:Listbox>

<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="toListBox" ></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: remaiing code is this 

<asp:ListBox ID="fromListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="150px" Width="150px"  >

<asp:ListItem Text="Student Enrollment ID" Value="enrollment_no"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Student Name" Value="first_name"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Last Name" Value="last_name"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Father Name" Value="father_name"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Date Of Birth" Value="DOB"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

<asp:listBox SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server" ID="toListBox"></asp:listBox>

Comment: i want to persist the value of both listBox on post back while i loose it pleasse suggest me an appropriate solutions

Comment: Do you find your code snippet readable? I don't. You should consider using 4 whitespaces at the beginning of each row instead of blockquoting with `>`. Also posting large code snippets in the comments section is useless for the same reasons of readability. I would encourage you to go ahead and edit your question.

Comment: i am quite poor in editing on it please edit it sir or let me know how should i edit it it's always a problem for me

Comment: Select the code snippet and press `Ctrl+K` while in edit mode.

Comment: hello i am in dire need to resolve this issue please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should use normal html listboxes, not asp.net server controls.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212988/listbox-elements-rearranged-with-javascript-causing-event-validation-error-on-pos) are some tips about it. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204140/moving-items-in-dual-listboxes--) you can find decent code for jquery that will move items beetween listboxes.

I think you have three options:

- Use normal HTML listboxes, write some javascript code, and manipulate with them on server using standard POST request.
- Use UpdatePanel with your listboxes (you'll eliminate page flickering and you probably wont have to use jQuery or rewrite your existing code)
- Find or write your own control that uses javascript to move items and manage viewstate itself

I would use HTML listboxes (select elements) to avoid viewstate issues. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: ok, you are true i can use update panel with list box but i wanted to learn it through the custom control.
Could you tell me how can i integrate ajax to my project i never did before what do i need to do ?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ListBoxComponent01.aspx
But really, don not create custom control that you'll use once or twice in your project. It's better to just create ascx with some javascript. It's much faster.